# Compact code for conditional replacement of values with an "OR" condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements, or-condition

I have a very long dataset and a relatively short list of ID values for which my data is wrong.
The following works, but my wrong_IDs vector is actually much larger:

```
wrong_IDs <- c('A1', 'B3', 'B7', 'Z31')
df$var1[df$var2 == 'A1' | df$var2 == 'B3' | df$var2 == 'B7' | df$var2 == 'Z31'] <- 0L
```

This looks very basic but I haven't found a compact way of writing this.
Thanks for any help

Comment: `df$var1[df$var2 %in% wrong_IDs] <- 0L`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare your data to the wrong_IDs with the %in% operator

```
df <- data.frame("var1" = 101:120, "var2" = c(1:20))
wrong_ids <- c(3, 5, 7)
df$var1[df$var2 %in% wrong_ids] <- 0
```

where df$var2 %in% wrong_ids provides you a TRUE/FALSE boolean vector that applies only the "set to zero" operation on the selected rows (here row 3, 5 and 7).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very compact solution using `grepl` and regex:

Some illustrative data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  ID = paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:3], 2), sample(1:3, 6, replace = T)),
  Var2 = rnorm(6),
  stringsAsFactors = F)
df

wrong_IDs <- c('A1', 'B3', 'B1', 'C3')
```

To set to 0 those rows that contain the `wrong_IDs` you can collapse these values into a single string separated only by the regex alternation operator `|` and instruct `grepl` to match these alternative patterns in `df$ID`:

```
df$ID <- ifelse(grepl(paste0(wrong_IDs, collapse = "|"), df$ID), 0, df$ID)
df
  ID        Var2
1  0  0.07050839
2  0  0.12928774
3 C2  1.71506499
4 A3  0.46091621
5  0 -1.26506123
6 C1 -0.68685285
```

Comment: thank you, but this goes beyond my needs and it is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: If you do `paste0(wrong_IDs, collapse = "|")`the result is `"A1|B3|B1|C3"`. The function `grepl` now looks to match either `A1` or `B3` or `B1`or `C3` in the `ID`column. If it finds a match, the respective row is returned, if it does not find one, the respective row is not returned. Does this help clarify the code?

Comment: Yes, this is now clear, thank you. This means that:
df[grepl(paste0(wrong_IDs, collapse = "|"), df$ID),] <- 0L 
would allow me to correct exactly those cell? I don't mean to be rude, I'm honestly wondering if this isn't unnecessarily complicated as compared to the other solution?

Comment: How to assess this solution is entirely up to you ;) I've updated it anyway.

Comment: Do feel free to accept the other solution which suits your needs better. But maybe this solution teaches you something new and may be useful for future queries.

Comment: it surely helps with the understanding of grepl and an ifelse statement. thank you :)